# Finding the greatest value of $a^2b^3c^2$ if $a+b+c=3$ and all numbers are positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find the greatest value of $a^2b^3c^2$ if $a+b+c=3$ and all numbers are positive.

Here is my attempt using $\text{AM-GM inequality}$:

$$AM=\frac{a+b+c+a+b+c+b}{7}$$
$$GM=\sqrt[7]{a^2b^3c^2}$$

We have to find the maximum value of the expression under the radical of the $GM$.

$GM$ will be maximum if all terms are equal. Hence,

$$a=b=c=1$$

So the maximum value of the expression should be $1$.

However, **this is wrong** (at least according to the problem book where I found this question).

I can't figure out what I did wrong. Can you help me?

*Source*: Resonance DLPD Algebra for JEE Mains and Advanced. Exercise 1, Part II, D-4.

*Motivation*: I am trying to practice mathematics problems for the JEE Mains and Advanced.

Comment: Please include the source (with enough info for someone else to look it up) and the motivation for each problem. Problems without motivation are discouraged on this site, which is a Q & A site rather than a problem solving site.

Comment: More information is at "How to ask a good question": https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @CarlMummert this problem is from a region-specific entrance exam preparation problem book. Including the name of the book won't help anyone as it isn't available outside of a few states in India. Also, what do you mean by lacking in motivation? I have showed how I attempted this question. Should I post monetary rewards to "motivate" fellow members?

Comment: !user69284: there is no reason not to include the specific name of the book and problem number; if you have the book and are interested, it stands to reason that other people could also have the book and be interested. By motivation I mean: why is this specific problem of interest? Just finding a problem in a book does not give much motivation for why anyone else would be interested in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM $$3=2\cdot\frac{a}{2}+3\cdot\frac{b}{3}+2\cdot\frac{c}{2}\geq7\sqrt[7]{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{b}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2}.$$
The equality occurs for $\frac{a}{2}=\frac{b}{3}=\frac{c}{2}$ and $a+b+c=3.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Awesome! But, why is @user69284's answer wrong?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Can you please point out exactly where the problem is? I am not very receptive when it comes to maths. Anyway, thanks for the awesome answer!

Comment: @user69284 Because  $2a+3b+2c$ is not constant for $a+b+c=3$, which says we can get a greater value than $1$, which you got.

Comment: @Dr. Mathva because in the maximal value the equality occurs not for $a=b=c$.